# Adding ?enablejsapi=1 to YouTube iframe Code

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have a Wordpress site and I have a custom field which holds YouTube iframe codes. There is a string holding these iframe codes named $embed. Videos are displayed in the theme with code:

```
<?php print($embed); ?>
```

I want to convert my standard YouTube embed codes such that:

Standard Youtube Embed Code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uxpDa-c-4Mc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Converted Format:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uxpDa-c-4Mc?enablejsapi=1&html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>
```

Simply, I want to add ?enablejsapi=1&html5=1 to end of URL and add id="video".

How can i obtain this iframe code by manipulating the parameter $embed?

Tnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add the extra params to the source. (Replace with your current `print($embed)` code.

```
// use preg_match to find iframe src
preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', $embed, $matches);
$src = $matches[1];

// add extra params to iframe src
$params = array(
    'enablejsapi'=> 1,
    'html5' => 1
);

$new_src = add_query_arg($params, $src);
$embed = str_replace($src, $new_src, $embed);
$embed = str_replace('></iframe>', ' ' . $attributes . '></iframe>', $embed);

print($embed);
```

Comment: Tnx. It perfectly work for adding enablejsapi and html5 to YouTube embed url. But it does not add id="video" part. It added something like id="fitvid555604". Probably $attributtes parameter does not work as you thought. Sorry, i have limited JS knowledge. Do you have an alternative method for adding id="video"? Tnx.

Comment: Oh i did it with replacing $embed = str_replace('></iframe>', ' id="video"></iframe>', $embed); Thank you very much for your help HdK.

Comment: Just leave the last str_replace out if you just want to change the src